# Table Missing Rows! Help!

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I'm trying to write up a table but I'm missing the vertical rows in the last few columns. Anyone have any clues as to how to fix this?

This is my code.
[image: This is my code]

However, it produces this output. How do I resolve the issue? 
[image: This is the output]